# How to get away from SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a listview with three items in it. `color_id`, `color_name`, and `color_count`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/color_id"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/color_name"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/color_count"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I load data from the server into my list. Here I'm adding data to the list manually for demonstration:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> colorsList = new ArrayList();

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap();
map.put("id", "1");
map.put("color_name", "red");
map.put("color_count", "10");
colorsList.add(map);
map = new HashMap();
map.put("id", "2");
map.put("color_name","yellow"):
map.put("color_count","15");
colorsList.add(map);

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
        MyActivity.this, colorsList,
        R.layout.list_item_colors, new String[] {"id",
        "color_name","color_count"}, new int[] {
        R.id.color_id, R.id.color_name, R.id.color_count});

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

**Question**

All this is working fine for me. However, for other reasons I want to part ways with `SimpleAdapter` and instead use `ArrayAdapter`  However, with `ArrayAdapter` 
I'm not sure how to set the three items I have :  `color_id`, `color_name`, and `color_count`

Comment: are you want using custom ListView with  ArrayAdapter  that hold textviews ??

Comment: Yes. I have ListView with multiple textviews in it and I don't want to use SimpleAdapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create your custom `ArrayAdapter` and  `ovveride` `getView()` method , this method which called each time you create item in list view and in it you will  inflate your layout (which contain textviews )and attach its data

there is good tutorial about `ListView` and custom one

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

and feel free to feed me back in any thing not obvious for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleAdapter.This is my demo.
The MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> colorsList;
private ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listcolor);

    colorsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("id", "1");
    map.put("color_name", "red");
    map.put("color_count", "10");
    colorsList.add(map);
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("id", "2");
    map.put("color_name","yellow");
    map.put("color_count","15");
    colorsList.add(map);
    SimpleAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(this,colorsList,R.layout.list_item_colors,
            new String[] {"id","color_name","color_count"},
            new int[] {R.id.color_id, R.id.color_name, R.id.color_count});
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

the XMl:
activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/listcolor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

the list_item_colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/color_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/color_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/color_count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```